# Would it be wrong to say "all in love" as in "all alone"?

Tags: phrases

I want to emphasize the concept of being completely in love, but for reasons I have to stick to a very short word, such as "all". Would it sound wrong if I said, "I'm all in love" (with someone)?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can, though *all in love* is an uncommon usage.

Usually *all* in this sense (*Oxford English Dictionary*, "[all, adj., pron., and n., adv., and conj.](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/5151)," def. C.1.a.(b)) would appear with *alone* or with another word, usually an adjective:

> 2010   A. R. Hawkins Year Money grew on Trees vii. 111   And look at you, you're **all filthy**!
>
> 1923   Glasgow Herald 10 May 9   He was **all confused** when taken to the presence of Her Majesty by a camerlengo.

Nothing prevents *all* from appearing with other phrases like *in love* though, meaning something like *wholly in love*, e.g.:

> JILL:... she had met someone and she was **all in love** with him. And she told me that he was her youth pastor and that her mom gave her blessing, and everyone loved him. (NBC Dateline, "Body of Evidence; Sean Goff accused of killing junior wife, Joy Risker," 15 July 2007, found via [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/))

> JAY: So, if you're **all in love** with her, what's the problem? (Chasing Amy, 1997; see ["Don't Make a Scene: Chasing Amy," Blogging by Cinema-Light](https://bloggingbycinemalight.blogspot.com/2021/01/dont-make-scene-chasing-amy.html))

Both these sources are spoken or intended to be spoken, so *all in love* may work for talking with someone but maybe less well for a formal written context.

Comment: There's Sherlock's memorable rhetorical question thrust at the agent he'd recently put in hospital: "Aren't _you_ all better!" It's an intensifier (thoroughly / really / completely). There are a few set phrases, but otherwise this use of 'all' is quirky / old-fashioned.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not said, it is not idiomatic. You'd have to use other devices to express something similar to thouroughness in such a context ; thouroughness is just not a concept that marries well with the idea of the mental state that is known as love; "Thouroughly" itself would not do ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=thouroughly++in+love&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=)); it is not idiomatic either. In standard English, you would say something such as "*truly in love*" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=truly+in+love&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctruly%20in%20love%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ctruly%20in%20love%3B%2Cc0)).

Comment: 'All shook up' is preferred to 'all shaken up' for some reason.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since about 2000, there is a reversal of the trend, so much so that presently there is not much difference in the frequency ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=all+shaken+up%2Call+shook+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Call%20shaken%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20shook%20up%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Call%20shaken%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Call%20shook%20up%3B%2Cc0)). As far as I can feel it seems that the reason has to do with the passing fancy of the users of the language. (1/2)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Anyway, OALD gives only "shaken" as the p.p. and I perceive "he was shook up" as non-standard, but the ngram tells another story ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+was+shook+up%2Che+was+shaken+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20was%20shook%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20shaken%20up%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20was%20shook%20up%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Che%20was%20shaken%20up%3B%2Cc0)). (2/2)

Comment: I wouldn't agree. "All" is fine, if casual, and "thoroughly" is completely natural, in my estimation. That said, I wouldn't consider them interchangeable.

Comment: "All aflutter' and 'all of a flutter' can be found in numerous references.

Comment: @Casey You must then approach this particular feeling (love) according to a would-be reality that does not recognize a  line between "love" and "no love" but instead a gradation  from "no love at all" to "full love" where love and "non love" can coexist; frankly, I find it difficult to conceive the question on that basis, but no less difficult to accept the other possibility. Let's look at a serious definition (SOED): "That state of feeling with regard to a person that manifests itself in concern for the person's welfare, pleasure in his or her presence, and often  (1/3)

Comment: @Casey also desire for his or her approval;". The points of concern then go on thinning out and/or diminishing in the positive intensity of the concern till full "no love" is reached; there must be a line that marks the departure from a series of states of ever weakening love to "no love at all". This is true in reverse and then three regions result: "full love", "neither full nor totally inexistant love", and no love; however, we agreed implicitly that  the togetherness of "full love" and "neither full nor totally inexistant love" is "love"; it follows that there is a   (2/3)

Comment: @Casey line between "love" and "no love at all". I have to conclude that the two lines are one and the same and that the middle region does not exist. I see no way out of this scheme. (3/3)

Comment: The ngrams make a fine demonstration of how a single person with enough clout can skew the language. Elvis, the modern Shakespeare. _Blue Suede Shoon_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That "shoon" had me panting for a few minutes, it must have been found no more than once in a blue moon in Elvis Presley's various interpretetations of *Blue Suede Shoes*; I finally found in the SOED that it is an actual plural of "shoe", but dialectal, archaic & poetic.